# Selenium - Não foi possivel fazer login ( navegador não seguro )

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, automatização

Olá, boa noite, estou tentando desenvolver um web bot em python, usando a biblioteca selenium e webdrive_manager, porem quando tento fazer login em minha conta do google usando o navegador que o bot está atuando, ele me retorna um erro dizendo que não foi possivel fazer login pelo navegador não ser seguro. alguem pode me ajudar? segue o erro e o código abaixo:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

browser = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
browser.get('https://classroom.google.com/u/0/h')
```

error:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

não sei se é algum mecanismo de defesa do google ou algum problema com o código, agradeço desde já!! há, e por curiosidade, o bot seria para acessar as aulas online automaticamente, por isso nescessito de fazer login nessa conta

Comment: Há [algumas restrições](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/7675428) para se fazer o login no Google.

Answer (score 0):

Provavelmente você tem que ativar aplicativos menos seguros em https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps, ao acessar clique no botão aonde está marcado DESATIVADA, como na imagem abaixo

> [image: Acesso a app menos seguro]

Outra possibilidade (mas menos provavel) é que sua conta do google use duplo-fator (mas não estou certo disso).

Ainda sim se a intenção é acessar contas aleatórias, que não possa definir essa permissão, então creio que não vá conseguir (não testei em outros drivers), esse sistema de permissão é justamente para a segurança do usuário.

Comment: Obrigaodo!, irei testar

Answer (score -2):

1. Crie uma conta nova do Google
2. Vá em https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps e ative a opção **Permitir aplicativos Menos Seguros**